# JPA saveAndFlush is returning correct updated entity but the updated entity is not persisted in database

Tags: java, json, jackson, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am writing a program using Spring-Boot that has `Person` and `Item` entities that are persisted to an in-memory HSQL database. `Person` has a OneToMany relationship with `Item`, and `Item` has a ManyToOne relationship with `Person`. For the front-end of my program I am planning to use AngularJS, so I need the back-end to return the entities is JSON format (I haven't gotten to actually write the front-end; I'm just using Postman to issue RESTful commands right now for testing the back-end). I originally was using `JsonManagedReference` and `JsonBackReference` on `Person` and `Item` to prevent the infinite recursion that would otherwise happen during JSON serialization, and while that correctly linked `Person` to `Item` in Json, it resulted in `Item` not having any refernce back to the 'Person` when returned as Json.

Instead, I decided to map `Person` and `Item` to different DTOs in the service layer which would then be returned as Json. It all seems to work until I try to associate an `Item` with a `Person`. I get the `Person` and `Item` by id, then add the `Item` to the `Person` and saveAndFlush. The saveAndFlush command returns an updated `Person` that contains the `Item` linked to it as Json, but as soon as I issue another request it's as if it had never happened. The link does not seem to be persisting. No exceptions are thrown, and when I used debug I confirmed that the object being passed as an argument to saveAndFlush does contain the updated `Person` with the linked `Item`. I can't figure out what's going wrong, and I would appreciate any help.

Please see my code on [GitHub here](https://github.com/compumike08/test-springboot-angularjs-project/tree/no-orm-library) (make sure you are viewing the "no-orm-library" branch, **NOT** "master").

UPDATE:

So, what I ended up doing was adding a new method to the ItemController and the ItemService for updating an existing item. Now, when the method in ItemService to updateExistingItem is called, an ItemDto is still passed in just like before. Except now, instead of converting the ItemDto to an item via the mapper, the ItemService extracts the item ID from the ItemDto, gets the Item with that ID from the ItemRepository, then updates the "checked" and "description" fields of that Item with the values from the ItemDto before saving the updated Item back to the database via the repository. This fixed the error I was expericing before. Now, I'm experiencing another problem. If I delete an Item after linking it to a Person, it deletes the Person it was linked to as well. I tried changing the CascadeType on the ownedItems List field in Person and on the ownedBy field in Item from ALL to MERGE and PERSIST, but then it just ignored all deletes (i.e. I would delete an Item but it would remain in the database as if I hadn't called delete on it. I never got any errors or exceptions, it simply just wouldn't persist any deletes). Since that didn't work, I changed the CascadeType back to ALL pending further research. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The JPA API doesn't have a method "saveAndFlush". Perhaps you mean some other API

Comment: When calling that `addOwningItem` on `Person` after adding it to the collection also call `setOwnedBy(this);` on the `Item`. The `Item` is controlling the relationship (as you have specified the `mappedBy` property on your relationship). Please add code to your post and don't let people search the internet for your code that isn't really helpful. Another pro tip remove `@Configuration` and `@ComponentScan` from your `@Controller` beans it adds nothing s everything is already detected by Spring Boot.

Comment: API wrapper you are using make sure entityManagerInstance.getTransaction().begin()/.commit() functions are properly called.

Comment: @M.Deinum: your comment worked! But now, after linking an `Item` to a `Person`, if I then update the `Item`'s "checked" field (or any other field), it gets unlinked from the `Person`. I realized that the `OwnedByPersonDto` inside the `ItemDto` wasn't getting converted to a `Person` when the parent `ItemDto` was converted to an `Item` during the update, so I added code to do that. But now I'm getting the following exception when I try to update the `Item` after it is linked: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity [mh.michael.model.Item#1] are being merged.

Comment: @BillyFrost: Sorry, my mistake. It's the spring-data specific implementation of the JpaRepository (org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository)

Comment: You should reuse the already created Person and not create a new one inside your mapper. Else you will run into this exception.